# Reportes con Spring boot 4

Tags: spring, spring-boot

buen día,
queria preguntar como puedo hacer para elegir el tipo de dato que voy a enviar por la URL utilizando la anotación de spring boot `@GetMapping` puesto que tengo un problema que siempre me envía la *exception*, error 400.
siempre solicita que el tipo de dato debe ser de tipo Long.

#### Controlador

```
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})

@GetMapping("/averias/reportes?desde={desde}&hasta={hasta}")


    public ResponseEntity<?> reportes(@PathVariable("desde") Date desde, @PathVariable("hasta") Date hasta){
            List<Averia> averia = null;
            Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            averia = averiaService.findByAllData(desde,hasta);
        } catch(DataAccessException e) {
            response.put("mensaje", "Error al realizar la consulta en la base de datos");
            response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": ").concat(e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage()));
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        if(averia == null) {
            response.put("mensaje", "Entre las fechas ".concat(desde.toString().concat(" y ").concat(hasta.toString().concat(" No se encontraron datos!"))));
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Averia>((Averia) averia, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

#### AveriaServiceImpl

```
@Override
    
@Transactional(readOnly = true)

    public List<Averia> findByAllData(Date desde, Date hasta) {
        return averiaDao.findByAllData(desde, hasta);
    }
```

#### Interfaz IAveriaService

```
public List <Averia> findByAllData(Date desde,Date hasta); //entre el list y el nombre de la funcion hay un List Averia con picoparentesis
```

#### consulta en IAveriaDao

```
@Query("SELECT a,c FROM Averia a, Compania c WHERE a.compania = c.comcodsx and a.avefecha BETWEEN :desde AND :hasta")

    public List<Averia> findByAllData(@Param("desde")Date desde, @Param("hasta")Date hasta);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo revisar la sección [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), el código debe ir como texto y no así como captura, ya que muy pocos se tomarán la molestia de typear tu código para replicar el error que tienes. Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problema Solucionado.
Sucedía que tomaba en la URL a la palabra "reportes" como una variable de tipo String, asi que cuando iba al Entity Averia buscaba una columna reportes a traves del ID del tipo Long, cual no iba a encontrar.
Se eliminó la palabra reportes del la URL y listo, funciono para consultar.

@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})

```
@GetMapping("/averias/?desde={desde}&hasta={hasta}") // <-- el error estaba aqui
public ResponseEntity<?> reportes(@RequestParam Date desde, @RequestParam Date hasta){
        List<Averia> averia = null;
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        averia = averiaService.findByAllData(desde,hasta);
    } catch(DataAccessException e) {
        response.put("mensaje", "Error al realizar la consulta en la base de datos");
        response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": ").concat(e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    if(averia == null) {
        response.put("mensaje", "Entre las fechas ".concat(desde.toString().concat(" y ").concat(hasta.toString().concat(" No se encontraron datos!"))));
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Averia>((Averia) averia, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

así quedo al final

Comment: Segun las buenas practicas para el diseño de una API, el formato `/averias/?desde={desde}&hasta={hasta}` es incorrecto porque las variables no beden ir despues de la pleca, antes de quitar reporte de la url tenia una forma mas clara de entender me parece que el error estaba en la forma en la cual llamas al servicio.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, lo que ocurre es que según la documentación de spring boot, la Url Generada no lleva en la URL el @RequestParam.

Ejemplo:
Si utilizas:

Toma a GetMapping para generar la URL base a la cual se va a dirigir
//GetMapping("/averias/reportes")

//RequestParam Genera los parametros de la URL que se van a invocar

public ResponseEntity<?> reportes(@RequestParam Date desde, //RequestParam Date hasta)

En pocas palabras configura la URL para que termine como
localhost:8080/averias/reportes?desde=2020-20-11&hasta=2020-21-11
RequestParam como GetMapping llevan arroba